# Extracting text from multiple spans with different classes using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data from a webpage that I've parsed through BeautifulSoup.

```
<div class="product-data-list data-points-en_GB">
<div class="float-left in-left col-totalNetAssets" style="height: 36px;">
<span class="caption">
Net Assets of Share Class
<span class="as-of-date">
as of 20-Jul-20
</span>
</span>
<span class="data">
USD 36,636,694,134
</span>
</div>
<div class="float-left in-right col-totalNetAssetsFundLevel">
<span class="caption">
Net Assets of Fund
<span class="as-of-date">
as of 20-Jul-20
</span>
</span>
<span class="data">
USD 37,992,258,237
</span>
</div>
<div class="float-left in-left col-baseCurrencyCode" style="height: 16px;">
<span class="caption">
Fund Base Currency
<span class="as-of-date">
</span>
</span>
<span class="data">
USD
</span>
</div>
```

I want to capture the information from the 'caption', 'as-of-date' and 'data' spans to create something like:
[('Net Assets of Share Class','20-Jul-20','USD 36,636,694,134'),
('Net Assets of Fund','20-Jul-20','USD 37,992,258,237'),
('Fund Base Currency','','USD')]

This is my code:

```
data=[]
for tag in soup.findAll("div", {"id": "keyFundFacts"}):
    for span in tag.findAll("div", {"class": "product-data-list data-points-en_GB"}):
        a = span.find("span", {"class": "caption"}).text
        b = span.find("span", {"class": "as-of-date"}).text
        c = span.find("span", {"class": "data"}).text
        data.append((a,b,c))
```

however, I only get 1 result when I look at the list 'data':

```
<pre>
[('\nNet Assets of Share Class\n\nas of 20-Jul-20\n\n', '\nas of 20-Jul-20\n', '\nUSD 36,636,694,134\n')]
</pre>
```

Aside from needing to strip out the new lines, I know I am missing something to get the script to go through all the other spans but have been staring at the screen for so long, it isn't getting any clearer.

Can anyone help put me out of my misery?!

Comment: since you are using span.find instead of span.findAll it is only return the first elements that contain the classes you defined.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to cycle through all the div elements that are under your main "div", {"class": "product-data-list data-points-en_GB" element. This way for each div element you will get the elements you want.

```
for tag in soup.findAll("div", {"id": "keyFundFacts"}):
    for element in tag.findAll("div", {"class": "product-data-list data-points-en_GB"}):
        for divEle in element.findAll('div')
            a = divEle.find("span", {"class": "caption"}).text
            b = divEle.find("span", {"class": "as-of-date"}).text
            c = divEle.find("span", {"class": "data"}).text
```

This makes for a lot of nested loops so I don't recommend this. I suggest finding a more precise way. If you have a url with the html I could take a look.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a look Timothee. I've needed to use selenium to get the payload but the site I am looking at is here:https://www.blackrock.com/uk/individual/products/253743/ishares-sp-500-b-ucits-etf-acc-fund?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true

Comment: Just by looking at the structure of the content at the url it does seem like you need to iterate through each section like above. I don't have the time now to look into it further but let me know if the above solution doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Timothee - the output from the code does say ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'' but not to worry - I'll keep tweaking it!

Comment: This means one of the objects may not have a certain data value - u can implement a simple try: and except block to catch any errors and keep trying all the other elements

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a solution which seems to do the trick:

```
data=[]
for tag in soup.findAll("div", {"id": "keyFundFacts"}):
    for element in tag.findAll("div", {"class": "product-data-list data-points-en_GB"}):
        for thing in element.findChildren('div'):
            a = thing.findNext("span", {"class": "caption"}).text
            b = thing.findNext("span", {"class": "as-of-date"}).text
            c = thing.findNext("span", {"class": "data"}).text
            data.append((a,b,c))
```

Its not perfect but hopefully functional.

thanks all